# BigDecimal notation eclipse plugin or nice external tool

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, bigdecimal

I need to make a lot of operations using BigDecimal, and I found having to express

```
Double a = b - c * d; //natural way
```

as

```
BigDecimal a = b.subtract(c.multiply(d))//BigDecimal way
```

is not only ugly, but a source of mistakes and communication problems between me and business analysts. They were perfectly able to read code with Doubles, but now they can't.

Of course a perfect solution will be java support for operator overloading, but since this not going to happen, I'm looking for an eclipse plugin or even an external tool that make an automatic conversion from "natural way" to "bigdecimal way".

I'm *not* trying to preprocess source code or dynamic translation or any complex thing, I just want something I can input text and get text, and keep the "natural way" as a comment in source code.

P.S.: I've found [this incredible smart hack](http://www.jroller.com/eu/entry/operation_overloading_in_java) but I don't want to start doing bytecode manipulation. Maybe I can use that to create a Natural2BigDecimal translator, but I don't want to reinvent the wheel if someone has already done such a tool.

I don't want to switch to Scala/Groovy/JavaScript and I also can't, company rules forbid anything but java in server side code.

Comment: I guess it's one of these "if you want something done right, do it yourself (Zorg, Fifth Element)" problems.

Comment: That only applies if you are really good at something. In my case, when I want something done right, I look for a well established open source project.

Comment: I think he's looking for a tool where you put in the arithmetic expression and you get the BigDecimal syntax to paste back into the source code, which should guarantee it to be error-free.

Comment: I disagree. I'm not faster typing BigDecimal notation, that is my fault, but I think in natural notation and I make mistakes translating to BigDecimal, and even if I were a perfect translator, I still need to write way more chars in BigDecimal notation. Also, I can ask business analysts to learn, but in this case I will expect them to make more mistakes, as they are learning something new. I consider 'my interest' to improve the quality of the final product I'm building, even adding some complexity to my development process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"I'm not trying to preprocess source code ... I just want something I can input [bigDecimal arithmetic expression] text".

Half of solving a problem is recognizing the problem for what it is. You *exactly* want something to preprocess your BigDecimal expressions to produce legal Java.

You have only two basic choices:

- A stand-alone  "domain specific language" and DSL compiler that accepts "standard" expressions and converts them directly to Java code.  (This is one kind of preprocessor). This leaves you with the problem of keeping all the expression fragments around, and somehow knowing where to put them in the Java code.
- A tool that reads the Java source text, finds such expressions, and converts them to BigDecimal in the text.  I'd suggest something that let you code the expressions outside the actual code and inserted the translation.

Perhaps (stolen from another answer):

```
 // BigDecimal a = b - c * d;
 BigDecimal a = b.subtract( c.multiply( d ) );
```

with the meaning "compile the big decimal expression in the comment into its java equivalent, and replace the following statement with that translation.

To implement the second idea, you need a [program transformation system](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/ProgramTransformation.html), which can apply source-to-source rewriting rules to transforms (generate as a special case of transform) the code.  This is just a preprocessor that is organized to be customizable to your needs.

Our [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html) with its [Java Front End](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/FrontEnds/JavaFrontEnd.html)  could do this.  You need a full Java parser to do that transformation part; you'll want name and type resolution so that you can parse/check the proposed expression for sanity.

While I agree that the as-is Java notation is ugly, and your proposal would make it prettier, my personal opinion is this isn't worth the effort.   You end up with a dependency on a complex tool (yes, DMS is complex: manipulating code isn't easy) for a rather marginal gain.

If you and your team wrote thousands of these formulas, or the writers of such formulas were Java-naive it might make sense.  In that case,
I'd go further, and simply insist you write the *standard* expression format where you need it.  You could customize the Java Front End to detect when the operand types were of decimal type, and do the rewriting for you.  Then you simply run this preprocessor before every Java compilation step.

Comment: I was writing a comment criticizing your answer and then I realize I don't like the answer **because is correct**. So I will accept it. I still don't think I need a full java parser, but something that parses a reasonable subset of Java, but that´s just my case, a general use tool will need a full java parser...I think we will need to get used to BigDecimal notation, or convince managers to allow us using Scala for this specific case. Or maybe [Xtext](http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/) is the answer, if we are willing to invest some time. Thanks for your advice!

Comment: Sometimes the truth is a little hard to swallow, I agree.   I doubt you can easily avoid a full parser; ultimately, you have to recognize the big decimal operands by their *type*, thus you need to capture all the declarations of identifiers and the details of the expressions.  You might be able to avoid doing a full parser, but being sure you don't need a part might be as hard as building it.  For the Java world, these are "easy enough" to get, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I agree, it's very cumbersome! I use proper documentation (comments before each equation) as the best "solution" to this.

```
// a = b - c * d;
BigDecimal a = b.subtract( c.multiply( d ) )
```

Comment: Seems like you and me are the only ones who don't like BigDecimal notation...   Quick advice, this is not an answer to my question, is just a comment, so post it as a comment, someone may (and probably will) downvote you

Answer (score 0):

You might go the route of an expression evaluator.  There is a decent (albeit paid) one at http://www.singularsys.com/jep.  Antlr has a rudimentary grammar that also does expression evaluation (tho I am not sure how it would perform) at http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Expression+evaluator.

Neither would give you the compile-time safety you would have with true operators.  You could also write the various algorithm-based classes in something like Scala, which does support operator overloading out of the box and would interoperate seamlessly with your other Java classes.