# How to improve Java calculate accuracy

Tags: java

in some cases I need to do really precise calculations in Java, but it always have some unexpected errors. How can I avoid them or keep the error in a acceptable range?

e.g.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    double x = 0.0;
    while (x <= 1.0){
        System.out.println(x);
        x += 0.1;
        System.out.println("add 0.1");
    }
}



- the result will be 

   0.0 add 0.1
   0.1 add 0.1
   0.2 add 0.1
   0.30000000000000004 add 0.1
   0.4 add 0.1
   0.5 add 0.1
   0.6 add 0.1
   0.7 add 0.1
   0.7999999999999999 add 0.1
   0.8999999999999999 add 0.1
   0.9999999999999999 add 0.1
```

which is not as expected.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the acceptable range?

Comment: you can refer to this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16234170/java-precise-calculations-options-to-use

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `BigDecimal` in these cases. It saves you from various deviations you will find working with `float` or `double`.

For more information, [Double vs. BigDecimal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413448/double-vs-bigdecimal)

http://www.opentaps.org/docs/index.php/How_to_Use_Java_BigDecimal:_A_Tutorial

Comment: BigDecimal is usually a bit overkill when people are just confused by the unformatted output of doubles.

Comment: In first line, OP says, "in some cases I need to do really precise calculations in Java".

Comment: I doubt he really does. He's not working in banking, that's for sure.

Comment: We should stick to answering the question, rather than assuming. I have answered as per the question. I have also provided with some links where OP can find more information. One of them clearly says that using `BigDecimal` is slow and is trickier to use. But who are we to decide what should be used where? OP needs some help, we provided it. That's it.

Comment: Well, based on the way the OP phrased his question, it's obvious that he has trouble understanding the formatting, not the accuracy. You develop an eye for these things after you've seen this exact type of question a dozen times.

Comment: My answer was based on my understanding of question. I will not accept any more comments on that. You also have provided your answer based on your understanding. OP will use whatever he likes.

Comment: I know it was based on your understanding. I commented to show you that the first understanding is not always the correct one. Often you need to dig the real question out of what has been posted, just because the OP doesn't exactly know what he should be asking for.

Comment: Thank you guys, I am just a student now. Maybe my question was not that professional which make you have some misunderstanding. My task now is a small project regarding financing, it should be really precise,so I think BigDecimal is exactly what I need now. Hopefully it will still be precise after a long chain of calculations.

Comment: Thanks @OliverCaffrey to clarify the confusion. Yes, `BigDecimal` is guaranteed to be accurate, irrespective of number of calculations since it is immutable. Please mark this answer correct if it solved your question.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using `BigDecimal` you should probably just format your double when you're printing it out.

Replace your println with `printf("%.1f\n", x);` and you'll get the output you're looking for.

`BigDecimal` is needed when you absolutely need to have precise accuracy during complex calculations (such as when money is involved).

Comment: Thanks, but my task now is assumed to be money involved so I need every step of calculation to be as precise as possible.

Comment: Then it's `BigDecimal` all the way, and pay attention to the scale and rounding mode.